# What PostgreSQL type is good for stroring array of strings and offering fast lookup afterwards

Tags: postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL 11.9

I have a table containing a jsonb column with arbitrary number of key-values. There is a requirement when we perform a search to include all values from this column as well. Searching in jsonb is quite slow so my plan is to create a trigger which will extract all the values from the jsonb column:

```
select t.* from app.t1, jsonb_each(column_jsonb) as t(k,v)
```

with something like this. And then insert the values in a newly created column in the same table so I can use this column for faster searches.

My question is what type would be most suitable for storing the keys and then searchin within them. Currently the search looks like this:

```
        CASE
            WHEN something IS NOT NULL
            THEN EXISTS(SELECT value FROM jsonb_each(column_jsonb) WHERE value::text ILIKE search_term)
        END
```

where the `search_term` is what the user entered from the front end.

Comment: Array of strings... in multiple rows.

Comment: There is no way speed up a search inside a JSON value that needs to iterate over all elements in order to use LIKE or ILIKE. Normalizing the key/value pairs into a separate table is your best chance

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Because... ?

Comment: Then you can index the values with a trigram index which is usable by `ILIKE`

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to be pretty, and normalizing the data model would be better.

You can define a function

```
CREATE FUNCTION jsonb_values_to_string(
   j jsonb,
   separator text DEFAULT ','
) RETURNS text LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT
   AS 'SELECT string_agg(value->>0, $2) FROM jsonb_each($1)';
```

Then you can query like

```
WHERE jsonb_values_to_string(column_jsonb, '|') ILIKE 'search_term'
```

and you can define a [trigram index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html) on the left hand side expression to speed it up.

Make sure that you choose a separator that does not occur in the data or the pattern...